# How to make a synchronous get request in javascript object macros of RiveScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rivescript

I’m new to rivescript i want to make a synchronous ajax get request in javascript object macros of RiveScript. I will be very grateful if anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: This question does not involve the Chat Bot language AIML, but instead the chat bot language RiveScript? These are two different languages. Can you explain the link with AIML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it. Note that the ajax call is **asynchronous**.

```
+ hello
- <call>sendData</call>

> object sendData javascript
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'myservice/username?id=some-unique-id');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            alert('User\'s name is ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
        else {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
    return "Done.";
< object
```